# Importing full ready map with carto.js v4?

Tags: carto, carto-js-v4

How do I import a whole map that is on my carto to edit it with carto.js v4?

It's pretty sad having to SQL to build the map from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I work at CARTO

Not at this moment. The current procedure in CARTO.js is to add the different layers one by one, both with the corresponding SQL and CartoCSS. This may change in the future but so far that's the procedure.